# Аппроксимация на php

Tags: php, алгоритм, математика

Нужно разобраться с аппроксимацией. Есть массив, допустим формата (формат может быть любой, это для примера)

```
[1517443199] => 10285.10000000
[1517702399] => 9199.96000000
[1517961599] => 7652.14000000
[1518220799] => 8683.92000000
[1518479999] => 8903.00000000
[1518739199] => 10000.09000000
[1518998399] => 10383.43000000
[1519257599] => 10437.60000000
[1519516799] => 9694.51000000
[1519775999] => 10569.04000000
[1520035199] => 11039.00000000
[1520294399] => 11454.00000000
[1520553599] => 9271.64000000
[1520812799] => 9533.57000000
[1521071999] => 8170.00000000
[1521331199] => 7824.80000000
[1521590399] => 8909.98000000
[1521849599] => 8898.03000000
[1522108799] => 8134.23000000
[1522367999] => 7090.14000000
[1522627199] => 6813.01000000
[1522886399] => 6796.10000000
[1523145599] => 6895.80000000
[1523404799] => 6843.90000000
[1523663999] => 7877.41000000
[1523923199] => 8064.92000000
[1524182399] => 8278.00000000
[1524441599] => 8787.02000000
[1524700799] => 8869.99000000
[1524959999] => 9348.00000000
[1525219199] => 9071.48000000
[1525478399] => 9713.99000000
[1525737599] => 9429.02000000
```

где ключ – координаты по оси oX, значение – координаты по оси oY.

Цель – аппроксимировать данные так чтобы график вышел максимально сглаженным (на самом деле количество данных в массиве на много-много больше). Для этого, как вы понимаете, на самом деле нужна интерполяция, но я решил посмотреть на результаты аппроксимации моего графика.

Нашёл метод для кусочно-линейной апроксимации на с++. Быстрым движением руки преобразил его под php.

```
function approximat($X, $Y, $x)
{
// вычисление ближайшего большего и его индекса
    $n = count($Y);
    $max = $X[0];
    $indexMax = 0;  // индекс
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        if ($X[$i] <= $max && $x <= $X[$i]) {
            $max = $X[$i];
            $indexMax = $i;
        }
    }

// вычисление ближайшего меньшего и его индекса

    $min = $X[$n];
    $indexMin = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
        if ($X[$i] >= $min && $x >= $X[$i]) {
            $min = $X[$i];
            $indexMin = $i;
        };
    }
    // вычисление нужного Y
        $Y = (($max - $x) / ($max - $min)) * $Y[$indexMin] + (($x - $min) / ($max - $min)) * $Y[$indexMax];
    return $Y;
}
```

Как применить пока не разобрался, нам нужно ведь по факту получить новый массив, как с точками в промежуточных значениях, так и с новыми значения в существующих.

Главный вопрос – помогите пожалуйста разобраться с самим алгоритмом аппроксимации.

```
for ($i = $data_x[0]; $i < $data_x[count($data_x) - 1]; $i = $i + 100) {
    $data_nx[] = $i;
}
$inter = [];
foreach ($data_nx as $x) {
    $inter[$x] = approximat($data_x, $data_y, $x);
}
```

data_nx - новые x-ы
data_y и data_x массивы координат.
[image: Результат на лицо]
Предполагаю что моя функция работает не совсем верно.(Исходя из провала в начале графика). Но в общем ок.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте посмотрел в сторону интерполяции, а не аппроксимации.

Comment: Верно подмечено) Интерполяцией я тоже занялся!

Comment: Создал тему по интерполяции https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825154/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте разбираться:

> $X - это массив с oX;
>
> $Y - это массив с oY;
>
> $x - это новое значение oX, для которого хотим получить oY.

Значит, если у ваш массив называется `$ARRAY`, то мы знаем как запихнуть туда первые 2 значения:

> $X = array_keys($ARRAY);
>
> $Y = array_values($ARRAY);
>
> Третий параметр - новое значение.

Исходя из этого, например, у вас есть массив `$ARRAY` с значениями, и нужно еще получить значения для массива `$NEW`, с координатами по `oX`: `1, 2 и 3`. Собсна:

```
$ARRAY = array(...);            //  Ваш массив
$X = array_values($ARRAY);   // Пихаем ключи (наши oX)
$Y = array_keys($ARRAY);         // Пихаем значения (наши oY)
$NEW = array(1,2,3);            //  Массив с oX, для которых надо найти oY
$RESULT = array();              //  Новый массив, где ключ будет oX, а значение oY

foreach ($NEW as $NEW_X)
{
    $RESULT[$NEW_X] = approximat($X, $Y, $NEW_X);
}
```

Теперь чтобы построить график у вас есть ваши точки в `$ARRAY`, и те которые были неизвестны (а было известно только `oX`) в `$RESULT`, а там разберетесь.

**P.S.** Это ни в коем случае не оптимальный пример, но оптимизацией займетесь сами.

Comment: Благодарю, похожим образом я пытался, но что-то пошло не так)

Comment: Внёс изменения в вопрос